# Where to get streaming (live) video and audio from camera example app for Android?

Tags: java, android, video, streaming, live

Where to get streaming (live) video and audio from camera example for Android?

Suppose I want to create some live video streaming service app so I'll have some cool server at the back end. And I know how to do that part. Suppose I have some stand alone app for PCs now I want to go on to mobile devices. So I want to see some sample app grabing audio and video streams from Phone, Synchronizing them, encoding somehow, and sending LIVE stream to server. I need any Open-Source sample that will do this or something like this. Where can I get such one?

Answer (score 2):

Ole have you been able to find any good examples of video or audio broadcasting yet? The best that I have found so far is the SIPDroid project ([www.sipdroid.org](http://www.sipdroid.org)). I haven't had a chance to review it in depth, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some project that you want

Ip Camera 
http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android

SipDroid
http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/ui/VideoCamera.java

You can get the codes using SVN or other clients.
Yet to me, the both projects still have issues. If you get the one working well, please tell me.